# Elected to be treated as a resident for income tax purposes: W-9 or W-8BEN?

Tags: usa, taxes, marriage, diplomats

A US citizen (A) marries a G-4 visa holder (B) who lives in the US.  They [elect to treat B as a resident alien for income tax purposes so they can file a joint tax return](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nonresident-spouse-treated-as-a-resident).

After the couple have made this election, B's bank asks for a [form W-8BEN](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf).  The [instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw8ben.pdf) say that one condition under which someone should not file W-8BEN is

> You are a U.S. citizen (even if you reside outside the United States) or other U.S. person (including a resident alien individual). Instead, use Form W-9 to document your status as a U.S. person.

Does the election mean that B should file W-9 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the election mean that B should file W-9 instead?

No.  B should continue to complete form W-8BEN.  The [instructions for form W-9](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9.pdf) say

> **Foreign person.** If you are a foreign person or the U.S. branch of a foreign bank that has elected to be treated as a U.S. person, do not use Form W-9. Instead, use the appropriate Form W-8 or Form 8233 (see Publication 515, Withholding of Tax on Nonresident Aliens and Foreign Entities).

(formatting in original)